# PHP foreach Loop and Mysqli Fetch associative array problem (Dublicated values)

Tags: php, arrays, select, foreach, mysqli

I simply need to check from database if Day is Blocked show in a select box as disabled and if NOT show the next 2 months all the days in the same select box.
I get the Closed(Blocked) days with no problem but when i am trying to get the rest of the days i get everything double.If NOT else for arrays not working.
The results show double like below :

Thursday, 30 Mar ,
Thursday, 30 Mar
and even the DISABLED day from the first loop shows double after looping.
Further clarification:
I am using the For Loop to get the next 2 months of dates. I am using the foreach loop to get the array with the days that are closed (Sunday, Monday)... So i want to show in the select box (Dates with Sunday or Monday disabled) and show the rest of the days Normal.

My sql

```
CREATE TABLE `check_availability` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Day` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Open_hour` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Closed_hour` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `ClosedDays` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Blocked` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `check_availability` (`id`, `Day`, `Open_hour`, `Closed_hour`, `ClosedDays`, `Blocked`) VALUES
(1, 'Sunday', '09:00am', '10:00pm', '', 1),
(2, 'Monday', '09:00am', '10:00pm', '', 1);
```

Mysqli fetch code. The array is correct. Array ( [0] => Array ( [Day] => Sunday ) [1] => Array ( [Day] => Monday ) )
On looping through the disabled days gets me all the dates which are Sunday  or Monday for 2 months correctly.

```
$sqlClosedDays   = "SELECT Day FROM check_availability WHERE Blocked ='1'";             
$resultClosed    = mysqli_query($con, $sqlClosedDays);
$DaysClosed   = mysqli_fetch_all($resultClosed,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

My for and Foreach loop that cause the dates to show double.

```
echo "<select name='add_r_date' id='add_r_date'>";
for($i=0;$i<=60;$i++){

    //Get the Closed Days   
    
    //Display the Days according to limit   
    $day=date('l,d M',strtotime("+$i day"));
    $InsDay = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+$i day"));   
    
    foreach ($DaysClosed as $rowDaysClosed) {   
        $dayClosed = $rowDaysClosed['Day'];
        $dayClosedTrim= substr($dayClosed, 0, 3);
        $dayTrim = substr($day, 0, 3);
        
        //If not Closed set as available
        if ($dayTrim === $dayClosedTrim ) { 
            echo "<option disabled value='$InsDay'>$day</option> "; 
            //$clDays[] = $day;     
        } else {
            echo "<option name='add_r_date' id='add_r_date' value='$InsDay'>$day</option>";
        }
    }//EOF FOREACH LOOP 
}//EOF FOR LOOP 
echo "</select>";
```

I tried unset($day); or unset($dayClosed);

I tried Break; inside the loops but the problem still there.

The problem it that the values show 2 times. I just want to show in disabled the days that are closed(Sunday) and (Monday) and show the rest days normal so that the people can select available dates to make reservation.

Comment: What does "double" mean? If you want to show the dates only once, why do you do that wihtin a `for`  loop?

Comment: Of course this does not work - you can not determine that a value is _not_ within a given list, _while_ you are still iterating over that list; you can only determine that, after you are done iterating over _all_ the items. Use a boolean flag that you toggle inside your loop when you found a match, and then react accordingly _after_ the loop.

Comment: @NicoHaase  I am using the For Loop to get the next 2 months of dates. I am using the foreach loop to get the array with the days that are closed (Sunday, Monday)... So i want to show in the select box (Dates with Sunday or Monday disabled) and show the rest of the days Normal.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also include your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: @CBroe Can you elaborate please what you mean boolean flag? I tried like assigning the returned array inside a variable $clDays[]=$day(it shows on the code commented) to get the dates that are found after looping through the array from the database but still i can not get it to work  since i still need to be inside the foreach loop..

Comment: You can only determine that the current day is an _open_ day, after you looped over and compared it to _all_ of your closed days. So do `$isOpenDay = true;` before your loop. Inside your loop, when you find a match, you toggle this flag to false. And then _after_ your loop, if that flag is still true, you output the option that you currently got in your else branch there.

Comment: _"Something with the $day array"_ - what array are you actually talking about now? `$day` is a _string_ value in the code you have shown, containing a formatted date.

Comment: @CBroe ..Yes sorry... my bad... ok i did follow your suggestion but still it doesnt change anything.. Still the values are shown 2 times. If for example i put the value $i to echo on the last else statement it will show the values twice such as  0 0 1 1 2 2  Sunday 02,Apr 3 3 and so on..

Comment: _"i did follow your suggestion"_ - I have no way of telling whether you did it correctly, based on just that. Please edit your question, and add what the current state of the code is.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your help and time. I am trying a different route now since i noticed that i have to check if there is closed days in database beforehand otherwise the whole code returns blank and also i need to count how many days are closed.etc. I will let the post know if i come with a solution.

Comment: _"have to check if there is closed days in database beforehand otherwise the whole code returns blank"_ - yes, because you are only creating option elements _inside_ the loop over that data. If you did it like I suggested, with a boolean flag - then that flag would still have the value it was initialized with, _after_ the loop that simply did nothing when there were not records, and you would know that you have to output the non-disabled option for that date now.

Comment: @CBroe Damn man... I finally got it right.. Thanks for the help.. The flags actually worked!! I just had to add another foreach loop checking the values and doing the flags. I also added on the beginning a check to database if there are any days closed to go through the first foreach loop otherwise it takes all the days. The second foreach loop basically checks the flags.. I also added some Break; to stop the loop from repeating. Thanks a lot.. You really helped with the flags suggestion.

Comment: @CBroe Also i added an array inside the first foreach loop $clDays[] = $day; that saved all the dates that are closed which i use to check on the second foreach loop.Maybe i need to clear the code little bit but its working for now..

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved thanks to @CBroe suggestion to add boolean flags before the loop and inside the loop. After i use those flags to check . Also i added Breaks to stop the looping. Lastly i added on the beginning of the code a check to the database if there exists any closing days.If not it outputs all the dates according to the for loop. Here is the working code.

```
 //SELECT START
  echo "<select name='add_r_date' id='add_r_date'>";
  for($i=0;$i<=30;$i++){
  //Get the Closed Days 
    //Display the Days according to limit   
  $day=date('l,d M',strtotime("+$i day"));
  $Nday = date('l',strtotime("+$i day"));
  $NdayTrim= substr($Nday, 0, 3);
  $InsDay = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+$i day")); 
  $counter = 0;
  //CHECK IF THERE ARE ANY CLOSED/BLOCKED DAYS
  if(count($DaysClosed ) != 0 ){
  $clDays[] ='';  
  $isOpen = 'true';
    foreach ($DaysClosed as $rowDaysClosed) {   
        $dayClosed = $rowDaysClosed['Day'];
        $dayClosedTrim= substr($dayClosed, 0, 3);
        $dayTrim = substr($day, 0, 3);
        
            //If not Closed set as available
            if ($dayTrim === $dayClosedTrim ) { 
                $isOpen = 'false';
                echo "<option disabled value='$InsDay'>$day</option> ";     
                $clDays[] = $day;   
            } 
            $counter++;         
        }//EOF FOREACH LOOP 
    
    $total_count=$counter;
        
        foreach ($clDays as $rowclDays) {
            $daycl = $rowclDays;
            
    if($daycl === $day && $total_count > 0) 
    {
    //    echo "<option disabled value='$InsDay'>$day</option> ";
            $isOpen = 'false';
    break;
    }
        else if($isOpen == 'true') {    
     echo "<option name='add_r_date' id='add_r_date' value='$InsDay'>$day</option>";
            break;
            } 
        }//EOF 2nd FOREACH 

    //IF there arent any closing days
    } else {    

echo "<option name='add_r_date' id='add_r_date' value='$InsDay'>$day</option>";
    
    }       
    }//EOF for loop     

    echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use DISTINCT method :

```
$sqlClosedDays   = "SELECT DISTINCT Day FROM check_availability WHERE Blocked ='1'";
```

or you can use GROUP BY method :

```
$sqlClosedDays   = "SELECT Day FROM check_availability WHERE Blocked ='1' GROUP BY Day";
```

Comment: The sample data that was shared does not contain any duplicated rows